# Making Use of Setcounter to Modify Makeindex Page Numbering

Tags: pdftex, page-numbering, indexing, makeindex, setcounter

I am working on a document wherein each chapter takes on a significance beyond the numerical value of the chapter itself.

I, for better or worse, have tried to incorporate this by making use of the `\setcounter{section}{}` command within each chapter.

In the following MWE, I have three chapters labelled 1, 2, and 3; and the counters are set, respectively, by 15, 30, and 45:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\large


\setcounter{section}{15}

\chapter*{1}

\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}
\textbf{\color{red}{Title for First Chapter}}\index{I would like \textbf{15} for the page number here instead of 1.}
\end{minipage}
\end{LARGE}
\end{center}

\lipsum[1]



\newpage

\setcounter{section}{30}

\chapter*{2}

\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}
\textbf{\color{red}{Title for Second Chapter}}\index{I would like \textbf{30} for the page number here instead of 2.}
\end{minipage}
\end{LARGE}
\end{center}

\lipsum[2]



\newpage

\setcounter{section}{45}

\chapter*{3}

\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}
\textbf{\color{red}{Title for Third Chapter}}\index{I would like \textbf{45} for the page number here instead of 3; etc.}
\end{minipage}
\end{LARGE}
\end{center}

\lipsum[3]

\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

which gives, the following index:

[image]

QUESTION: Instead of the displayed page numbers which reflect the page number on which the chapter occurs, I would like to display the counter values on those pages, which in this case, are 15, 30, and 45. Is this possible, and if so, how may the MWE be modified to accomplish this with Pdflatex? I have not been too successful in the past with changing the index page default in the past.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't uderstand what it is that you want your readers to know. If you use David Using David Carlisle's answer and `\index` items on the second or subsequent chapter pages and then they will appear in the index with your "section number".  This is really no help to a reader if the chapter has many pages; why do they have to plough through all of them to find the indexed item? Your MWE had no sections, how is the reader to know what, say, **15** refers to.

Comment: @Peter Wilson As MWE implies---*minimal*. The objective was put forth in the question and it was very satisfactorily answered. That is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to copy the definition of index you are using and replace `\thepage` by `\arabic{section}` (you can't use `\thesection` as that prefixes everything with 0. due to the unused chapter counter.

[image]

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\def\@wrindex#1#2{%
\imki@wrindexentrysplit {#1}{#2}{\arabic{section}}\endgroup \imki@showidxentry
{#1}{#2}\@esphack}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\large


\setcounter{section}{15}

\chapter*{1}

\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}
\textbf{\color{red}{Title for First Chapter}}\index{I would like \textbf{15} for the page number here instead of 1.}
\end{minipage}
\end{LARGE}
\end{center}

\lipsum[1]



\newpage

\setcounter{section}{30}

\chapter*{2}

\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}
\textbf{\color{red}{Title for Second Chapter}}\index{I would like \textbf{30} for the page number here instead of 2.}
\end{minipage}
\end{LARGE}
\end{center}

\lipsum[2]



\newpage

\setcounter{section}{45}

\chapter*{3}

\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}
\textbf{\color{red}{Title for Third Chapter}}\index{I would like \textbf{45} for the page number here instead of 3; etc.}
\end{minipage}
\end{LARGE}
\end{center}

\lipsum[3]

\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks once again for a most helpful answer.